# PyCharm outputs no text while reading file

Tags: python, syntax, pycharm

I am new to Python and I have programmed a very basic program which opens a pre-made file reads it, then closes it, through normal Python syntax:

```
f = open("file", "r+")
f.read()
f.close()
```

However, once run, this program produces no output.

Is there a problem with my syntax, or is there an error in my PyCharm installation?

Comment: ...what output were you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is supposed to happen. `f.read()` does not print things to the screen. It returns them, just like `open()` returns `f`.  If you want to print things, you need to call the [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function (under Python 3) or use the [`print`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) statement (under Python 2).